# How many times Yudhistir's coronation happened and when in the Mahabharata?

Tags: mahabharata, yudhisthira

It seems there is various versions of Yudhistir's coronation. One before the war. One after the war. Which of these is authentic and when did the coronation take place w.r.t war?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Yudhisthira became **yuvraj of Hastinapur** just before Lakshagrah incident.
2. After false news of Yudhisthira's death in Lakshagrah incident, Duryodhan became yuvraj of Hastinapur. But when Yudhisthira found alive in Draupadi svyamvar, he was appointed as the **king of Indraprastha**.
3. He became **Samrat** after Rajsuya yajna.
4. Later he lost his kingdom in *dhyut-krida* to Duryodhan and got 12+1 year exile. After Mahabharata war, he became the **king of Hastinapur**.
5. Later, he performed many yajna and became **Samrat**.

> Please visit [this research article](https://hindunet.org/hindu_history/ancient/mahabharat/mahab_patnaik.html) for timelines.

Comment: Thanks YDS. Do you know the exact duration between first Rajasuya to exile. Also duration between  finish of exile to start of war. Basically I need to know exact duration from first Rajasuya to start of war.

Comment: @Rama27 provided a link in my answer.

Comment: I have seen this link earlier. It does not make much sense chronologically.